# Number of real roots of equation

Tags: real-analysis, roots

Given $\cos(x)=ax$, express the number of real roots as a function of $a$.

I've found that the sign of $a$ doesn't matter since $cos(x)$ is an even function, and that the number of roots increases as the value of $a$ decreases, for infinitely many roots as $a$ approaches zero. But I have no idea where to go from there.

I know that $\cos(x)=x$ is unsolvable analytically, so is this question also only solvable numerically?

Comment: Hello. Interesting problem!!

Comment: Note that $\left| \cos (x)\right| \leq 1$, and for $a\neq 0$, we have $\left| a x \right| > 1$ as soon as $x > ...$. So this should tell you that all solutions of the equation are found inside a bounded interval. Now you just need to find this interval and then count the solutions inside this interval, which sounds easier than counting solutions all over the real line.

Comment: *"for infinitely many roots as a approaches zero."* That part is false. It is true that there are infinitely many roots if $a=0$. But for every $a\neq 0$ there should be only finitely many roots.

Answer (score 4):

Since $x=0$ is never a solution, the equation $\cos x = a x$ is equivalent to $\frac{\cos x}{x}=a$

Then the number of solution of the equation reduces to finding the maxima and minima of the function $f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{x}$. For example, in the graph we can see that there exists $4$ solutions for $a = 0.1612\ldots$ (the top horizontal), $5$ solutions between the two horizontals, $6$ solutions for $a = 0.1067\ldots$ (the bottom horizontal).

[image]

To find those critical points you need to solve $f'(x)=0$, which is equivalent to $\cot x = -x$. This equation has not an analytic solution but the roots can be found numerically.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but this Geogebra screenshot shows how beautiful this question can become, for values $a \approx 0.35$ and $a \approx 0.15$ (the second one is shown as "b" in the screenshot):

[image]